# Read text file using java

Tags: java

I have a text file contain two data in two line

```
admin
temp123
```

I want to read the text file and store this text to two string for further use.
like,

```
String username = "admin";
String password = "temp123";
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: see https://www.journaldev.com/867/java-read-text-file

Comment: Please post your attempt at solving the issue with the relevant code and where the code is not working like you expect.  It will make it a lot easier for people to help you and see where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simple google search would have done the job. Check these link: 
 - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/ 
 - https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use this for login credentials for something in your application. I would suggest that you look into working with .properties files to get your values, as in the end the java Properties class will handle reading the file and iterating through the key, value pairs it contains.

Example text file:

```
username=myUser
password=myC0mpLicat3dPa$$W0rd
```

Java Code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("myTextFileHere.properties"));

String username = prop.getProperty("username"); // assigned value of "myUser"
String password = prop.getProperty("password"); // assigned value of "myC0mpLicat3dPa$$W0rd"
```

This will be much simpler than iterating the file, and I imagine more efficient when you decide to work with reading more than two variables in the future.